# Using substring in SQL update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, substring

I'm writing a SQL query that updates the CUST_NAME column by appending the the word "CHECKED to it. The column is only 100 characters long however and I'm going to run into errors if I have an already long customer name and try appending CHECKED to it. So I want to use the Substring function in sql, but kind of stumped. I want to be able to substring the CUST_NAME field if it will go over 100 characters with the appended word. How can I do that?
Thank you

```
UPDATE CUST_INFO cust
  SET CUST_NAME = (CUST_NAME||'_CHECKED')
  WHERE process_timestamp = null;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
UPDATE CUST_INFO cust
    SET CUST_NAME = SUBSTR(CUST_NAME, 1, 92) || '_CHECKED'
    WHERE process_timestamp is null;
```

Also, if you want to update any records, then use `is null` rather than `= null` (the latter never evaluates to true).

Note:  Not all databases have the `left()` function, you can use `substr()` or the equivalent instead.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using oracle's substr() function like this:
(SUBSTR(CUST_NAME,0,92)||'_CHECKED')